# why does this layout take 2-7 seconds to render in the UI?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

So I have a layout with a RecyclerView That is taking between 2 and 7 seconds to load 7 items and show them in the list.

I ran the Android Studio profiler on the CPU using Sample Java methods and it appears that the bulk of the wait time is happening in the drawing and measuring of the views.  60% inRun() from FrameDisplayEventReceiver and nested under that call 53% by the first onMeasure() call.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that the cause of the slowness is a poorly designed xml layout.

Can any one show my what I've done in this layout that makes it run slowly and how I can make it more efficient?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/id_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/id_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateTint="#795548"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/id_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/image_1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text_1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/id_4"
        android:name="com.company.MyFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"

        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/id_1"
        tools:context="MyFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_routeitem"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/id_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:rippleColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Code as Request (Kotlin)

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_routeitem_list, container, false)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar.title = resources.getString(R.string.my_route_title)
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.my_routes_loading)
    emptyStateView = view.findViewById(R.id.empty_state)
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.my_routs_list)
    dataAdapter = MyRouteItemRecyclerViewAdapter(mutableListOf(), this)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.adapter = dataAdapter
    startLoadData()

    val newRouteFab: FloatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.new_route_fab)
    newRouteFab.setOnClickListener {
        createNewRoute()
    }


    return view
}



fun startLoadData() {
    launch{
        val routeList: List<Route> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            Application.getDaoSession()
                    .routeDao
                    .queryBuilder()
                    .where(RouteDao.Properties.Id.isNotNull)
                    .orderDesc(RouteDao.Properties.VisibleModified)
                    .build().list()
        }
        setData(routeList.toMutableList())
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

Comment: Layout looks fine. The delay is probably because of however you collect, build and assign data.

Comment: Can you post the associated Java?

Comment: The layout seems all right. Nested weight in linear layout makes layouts slow. But you haven't used nested weight. Please add the Java code

Comment: if you need more speed try to use `Anko` [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/400-faster-layouts-with-anko-da17f32c45dd)

Comment: I've added the code, it's in Kotlin.